# Is there any X windows system, which is HTML, CSS, Javascript? Such as Web Browser?

Tags: kernel, xorg, arch-linux, x11, gui

For dacades X windows system is either BASH, C or etc. But is there any X windows system or any wrapper which can interpret HTML, CSS, Javascript to general Windows system?

I would like to build this: http://www.google.com/tv/features.html
(everything comes from my web server, and get render as UI)

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ǝʃƃoo⅁ ɹɐǝ◖

while I'm not aware of anything that fits your description, you could have a look at [the Mozilla Project's "Chromeless":](http://mozillalabs.com/chromeless)

> Instead building a whole new platform, we suggest that the web itself should be the platform. That a developer could design the browser using standard web technologies combined with a minimal set of new APIs to interact with the underlying operating system and control the application's user interface.

It's supposed to be a the-browser-is-the-OS thingy like (your, haha) *Chrome OS*.

Also have a look at [Symphony OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_OS) with their [Mezzo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezzo_%28desktop_environment%29) desktop environment, I don't know any details, but apparently they use some Mozilla base, too, so the desktop environment includes HTML, JS, even Flash.

Last but not least, the GNOME project could be interesting, for one thing, GNOME Shell is full of Javascript and [Metacity at least has experimental CSS styling.](http://blogs.gnome.org/metacity/2009/07/18/more-css-thoughts/)

Oh, and the whole issue gets turned upside down if you consider [GTK3's HTML5 backend.](http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2010/11/23/gtk3-vs-html5/)

Comment: Note that that still would require X to handle the whole "talking to the kernel and graphics hardware" stuff. But it's not a particularly well thought out question.